# How to update my list of dictionary with nested for loops?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Here I am trying to update the the list of dictionary like this but I am not getting the desired output. How can I solve this ?

```
 def get_values(self):

    list1 =  [{'key1': 'value1'}, {'key2': 'value2'}]

    list2 = [100, 200]
    for i in list1:
        for j in list2:
            i['val']=j
    return list1
```

The current output is

```
[{"key1": "value1","val": 200},{"key2": "value2","val": 200}],
```

The output I want is:

```
[{"key1": "value1","val": 100},{"key2": "value2","val": 200}],
```

Comment: I suggest tracing through every iteration of the inner and outer loops to learn what's going on for yourself and how for loops work.

Comment: @mkrieger1 yes it answered. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can write a *list comprehension* using [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to achieve this. Below are few alternatives to achieve this in different Python versions.

In **Python 3.9.0+**, using `|`:

```
>>> list1 =  [{'key1': 'value1'}, {'key2': 'value2'}]
>>> list2 = [100, 200]

>>> [l1 | {'val': v} for l1, v in zip(list1, list2)]
[{'key1': 'value1', 'val': 100}, {'key2': 'value2', 'val': 200}]
```

In **Python 3.5+** using `**`

```
>>> [{**l1, 'val': v} for l1, v in zip(list1, list2)]
[{'key1': 'value1', 'val': 100}, {'key2': 'value2', 'val': 200}]
```

---

**Issue with your code** is that your are doing nested iteration of list `list2` for both the values of `list1`, because of which `'val'` is firstly getting set as `100` and then `200`, and your dictionaries are preserving the last value of `list2` i.e. 200. `zip()` will let you iterate both the iterables together by fetching element corresponding to same index from both the lists.

Hence, you code using explicit `for` loop could be written using [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) as:

```
list1 =  [{'key1': 'value1'}, {'key2': 'value2'}]
list2 = [100, 200]

for i, j in zip(list1, list2):
    i['val'] = j
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over both lists at the same time.

Python has a function [**`zip`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) useful for this. It pairs together each position in two (or more) sequences.

In this example we're using strings here as sequences of characters, just to be brief:

```
>>> list(zip('abc', '123'))
[('a', '1'), ('b', '2'), ('c', '3')]
```

So, you can fix your function:

```
def get_values(self):

    list1 =  [{'key1': 'value1'}, {'key2': 'value2'}]

    list2 = [100, 200]
    
    for d, n in zip(list1, list2):
        d['val'] = n

    return list1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this also without zip

```
list1 =  [{'key1': 'value1'}, {'key2': 'value2'}]
list2 = [100, 200]


for index, dictionary in enumerate(list1):
    dictionary['val']=list2[index]

print(list1)
```